# Setting default RTO (Retransmit Timeout) value in ns-3 simulator

Tags: tcp, ns-3, retransmit-timeout

I found this in rtt-estimator.h the constructor sets the value for `m_initialEstimatedRtt` which I believe directly controls the Retransmit Timeout value.

I am not sure how to set the value for `m_initialEstimatedRtt`.

I see a method named `SetCurrentEstimate` that could be used to change that value but I am not sure at what stage in the simulation I should modify it if I use that so I prefer to control the initial.

Also I'm wondering what is the default value set in the examples and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to set that variable, chiefly through the attribute system. The attriobute associated to that variable is ns3::RttEstimator::InitialEstimation from rtt-estimator.cc)

If you have followed the standard script layout, all you need is to use the following command-line argument:

```
--ns3::RttEstimator::InitialEstimation=1.0s
```

The tutorial gives a gentle introduction to the use of attributes through the command-line and environment variables:
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.19/tutorial/html/tweaking.html#using-command-line-arguments

There are more details there:
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.19/manual/html/attributes.html

You might find the ConfigStore useful too:
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.19/manual/html/attributes.html#configstore

Comment: Don't forget about setting --ns3::TcpSocketBase::MinRto as well!